# Count Number Of NOT NULL Columns for a particular Row id (Query)

Tags: mysql, sql, count, database

I need to extract the "COUNT OF THE NUMBER OF NOT NULL COLUMNS FOR A PARTICULAR ROW" in any db .

ANYTHING ?...

THANKS, cheers !

Comment: What is your table structure? How are you finding a "particular row"? If you don't want to explicitly reference all your columns then you will have to use dynamic sql, but all this would do is dynamically create the statements given in the answers here). You could speed up the writing of this query using something like `SELECT 'CASE WHEN `' + Column_Name + '` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + ' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'yourtable'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look this option to get all the field names which are not null:

```
show columns from TABLE_NAME where Null = 'NO';
```

Run this query from PHP and try to get count of this query through mysql_num_rows.

Comment: i am using struts2 with hibernate3,...how can i use this ?

Comment: @KennyWeeler you need to find out the function in your technology which returns number of rows

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of

```
SELECT 
(
 (CASE WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 + (CASE WHEN col2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 ...) AS count_of_not_nulls
FROM table t
WHERE t.Id= @ROW_ID
```

Comment: Guys...really sorry but..what if i have like a 1000 columns ?...i cant just input all the columns in the query if i use this right ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select 
     if(name1 = 0, 0, 1) +
     if(name2 = 0, 0, 1) +
     if(name3 = 0, 0, 1) as NumMsg
 from attributes where `id`='5'
```